# Can I write a module/filter that gets fired before the web app get's run in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, pipeline

Can I write a module/filter that gets put into the processing pipleline in Tomcat BEFORE the web application even gets run?

Something that I could turn on/off for each web application that tomcat is handling.

is this possible?

So basically it would be a re-usable filter that hooks into the web pipeline that could alter the requests behavior or perform/modify the requests.  One example would be to log all ip's, or redirect based on the url, block the request, etc.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. You're first asking for something to hook on webapp's startup for which a `ServletContextListener` is the right answer, but thereafter you're talking about filtering requests for which you would use a normal `Filter`. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Servlet 3.0 you can. What you do is implement either a `ServletContextListener` or a `ServletContainerInitializer`. The code below shows with`ServletContextListener`

```
@WebListener("auto config listeners")
public class MyListenerConfigurator implements ServletContextListener {
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent scEvt) {
      ServletContext ctx = scEvt.getServletContext();
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic reg = ctx.addFilter("myFilter", "my.listener.class.MyListener");
      ...
   }
```

See EE6 docs [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/). Perhaps the only drawback is that you can add but you cannot remove. And you can only at when the application starts up.

Note: code not tested

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a ServletContextListener in web.xml?

Comment: Is that something that could be hosted externally to a particular webapp?  i.e. would the listeners .jar be stored outside of the scope of a web app, so other web apps could use it?

Comment: It is found through the normal web app classloader, so your question is essentially a deployment issue.  Personally I like my WAR's to be self contained.  If you want a global configuration file for your WARs then consider an EAR deployment, or a property file in the web container itself.